# Tomcat Jersey Class Not Found

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jersey

I was following [this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html) tutorial on Tomcat and Jersey, but when I try to access it, I get a not found error, and this is output in Eclipse:
SEVERE: Servlet /de.vogella.jersey.first threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer

I am using JRE1.7, Eclipse, and the latest version of Jersey.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qnd2B.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcCBT.png) is what my setup looks like in Eclipse. I tried to keep all of the names the same, but haven't had much luck.

[This](http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html) was the tutorial I was attempting to follow.

Any help appreciated, Thanks~

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you include the jersey-servlet.jar in the class path? Take a look [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc:%22com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer%22) to get jersey-servlet.jar

Comment: This was it, thanks...it looks like I had everything else jersey except that!

Answer (score -1):

You also have to put Jersey jar files in the Tomcat lib folder